3.5mm jack adapter to Lightning doesn’t work
The new iPhone doesn’t have an audio jack, so I got an adapter to connect my AiAiAi headphones to Lightning connector and it only worked intermittently for music, but it’s useless for taking calls.
How can I fix this?
Here’s the adapter:


I‘ve used the adapter sold by Apple for years without problems. So, I would assume that your adapter is just broken and get a new one.
One thing to look out for is that it actually supports microphones as well. I imagine that cheap adapters just do audio-out. This one from Apple for sure should work.

Thank you! I’ll give this a try.
